# How do I empty my array into an email

Tags: php

I have a dynamically generated array as follows:

```
array(9) {
["action"]=>
string(15) "bookingrequest2"
["course-select-1"]=>
string(24) "Royal Troon - Old Course"
["course-select-2"]=>
string(16) "Royal Troon - New Course"
["accomodation"]=>
string(17) "Carlton Prestwick"
["singles"]=>
string(1) "2"
["twins"]=>
string(1) "2"
["doubles"]=>
string(1) "2"
["cartype"]=>
string(10) "Category C"
["notes"]=>
string(10) "some notes"
}
```

I am currently able to get the following easily as these are fixed form fields form the form.

```
   $accomodation = ($_POST['accomodation']);
   $singles = ($_POST['singles']);
   $twins = ($_POST['twins']);
   $doubles = ($_POST['doubles']);
   $cartype = ($_POST['cartype']);
   $notes = ($_POST['notes']);
```

However, the other values (course names) from [course-select-1] and [course-select-2] are dynamic. One form submission might contain x5 course-select, another may contain x20.

What Im looking for is  is a way to end up with the following :

```
foreach ($courses as $course){
   echo 'Day number' . $i . ' : ' $coursename;
}


(Day Number 1 : Royal Troon - Old Course)
(Day Number 2 : Royal Troon - New Course)
```

Comment: From where does the day number `1` come from?

Comment: This will be the HTML in my email for each course-select. This will need to be an incremental value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of your courses key are like `course-select-XX`, you can try to match these keys in a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value)
{
  if( substr( $key, 0, 14) == 'course-select-')
  {
     echo 'Day number' . $i . ' : ' . $value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that just broke everything lol. Im guessing I've missed some syntax there. All the keys are like course-select-XX. Could you edit your answer to reflect this please.

Comment: Looks like i forgot a `.` before in '' : ' . $value;', do you want to try again ?